# How do you include an attribute from a lower level include in an ancestor attribute set?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

A question for those familiar with Sequalize (MySQL). Does anyone know the correct method to place an attribute from a nested include within the attribute set above?

Example Sequelize request...

```
const pupils = await sequelize.Pupil.findByPk(1, {
    attributes: ['id','name'],
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.PupilGrade,
            as: 'pupilGrades',
            attributes: ['id','pupilId','subjectId','grade'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.Subject,
                    as: 'subject',
                    attributes: ['id','name'],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```

Resulting array...

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": 'Pupil A',
        "pupilGrades": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "pupilId": 1,
                "subjectId": 1,                 
                "grade": 'B+',
                "subject": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Math"
                }
            },              
        ],
    },
]
```

Desired array...

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": 'Pupil A',
        "pupilGrades": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "pupilId": 1,
                "subject": "Math",
                "grade": 'B+',
            },              
        ],
    },
]
```

I would like to know how to include the 'name' attribute from 'Subject' within the attribute set of 'PupilGrades'.

I have tried using Sequelize.col()...

```
[Sequelize.col('subject.name'), 'subject'],
```

However, it thinks subject is a attribute not an include table and returns:

```
Error: Unknown column 'pupil->pupilGrades.subject.name'
```

I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this at the include level having tried the following:

```
        {
            model: sequelize.PupilGrade,
            as: 'pupilGrades',
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'pupilId',
                'subjectId',
                'grade',
                [Sequelize.col('subject.name'), 'name'],
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.Subject,
                    as: 'subject',
                    attributes: ['id','name'],
                },
            ],
        },
```

Any help much appreciated.

I have tried the following as per Emma's suggestion.

```
[Sequelize.literal('`pupilGrades->subject`.name'), 'subject'],
```

After further tests it looks like there is an issue with Sequelize.

```
const pupil = await req.db.Pupil.findByPk(1, {
    logging: console.log,
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
    ],
    include: [
        { 
            model: req.db.PupilGrade,
            as: 'pupilGrades',
            attributes: ['id','pupilId','subjectId','grade',
                [Sequelize.literal('`pupilGrades->subject`.name'), 'subject'],
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: req.db.Subject,
                    as: 'subject',
                    attributes: [],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```

The code above generates the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
`Pupil`.`id`,
`Pupil`.`name`, 
`pupilGrades`.`id` AS `pupilGrades.id`,
`pupilGrades`.`pupil_id` AS `pupilGrades.pupilId`,
`pupilGrades`.`subject_id` AS `pupilGrades.subjectId`, 
`pupilGrades`.`grade` AS `pupilGrades.grade`, 
`pupilGrades->subject`.name AS `pupilGrades.subject`
FROM `pupil` AS `Pupil`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `pupil_grade` AS `pupilGrades` ON `Pupil`.`id` = `pupilGrades`.`pupil_id` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `subject` AS `pupilGrades->subject` ON `pupilGrades`.`subject_id` = `pupilGrades->subject`.`id` 
WHERE `Pupil`.`id` = 1;
```

Returning the correct dataset:

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | name    | pupilGrades.id | pupilGrades.pupilId | pupilGrades.subjectId | pupilGrades.grade | pupilGrades.subject |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Pupil A |              1 |                   1 |                     1 | B+                | Math                |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

However, Sequelize returns the following object with the pupilGrades.subject column missing.

```
{
    "pupil":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Pupil A",
        "pupilGrades":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "pupilId":1,
                "subjectId":1,
                "grade":"B+"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your syntax with `Sequelize.col` doesn't work but you can try this. `Sequelize.col` supposed to escape the aliases correctly, however, it didn't in your case. If I find something, I will update this answer.

AFAIK, it doesn't work when I add `Sequelize.col` to where a model is aliased (`pupilGrades`). If I add `Sequelize.col` to top level, I don't see any problems.

```
{
    model: sequelize.PupilGrade,
    as: 'pupilGrades',
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'pupilId',
        'grade',
        [Sequelize.literal('`pupilGrades->subject`.name'), 'subject_name'],
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.Subject,
            as: 'subject',
            attributes: [],  // Do not need sub nested object
        },
    ],
},
```

** Note that I cannot use the same alias name in associated model and attributes in same query.

Comment: Hi Emma, thanks for the help and pointers. I have updated my question with your suggestions.

Comment: Could you show the generated SQL when you tried the full path?

Comment: Hi Emma, I've added the SQL output. Your code generate the correct SQL result, however the object returned by Sequelize doesn't contain it.

Comment: I found the issue. I cannot alias with the attribute as same as the association alias.  If I change to `[Sequelize.literal(..., 'subject_name']`, this will return the value.  Or I think it also works if I rename the association alias.

Comment: Hi Emma, yes that resolved it. Thanks for your help in solving it, I am not sure I'd have spotted that!